# Is there a go-to way to install CuPy on Windows 10 right now?

Tags: python-3.x, windows, cupy

I can see that the installation guide:
https://docs.cupy.dev/en/stable/install.html
is quite outdated and a note on the Github release page of v9.0.0a2:
https://github.com/cupy/cupy/releases/tag/v9.0.0a2
states that the older version supporting CUDA v11.1 did not work in the first place and all wheels have been removed from PyPi as a response. Trying to install CuPy with an updated pip, none of the wheels are back up. Is there still a version (for any CUDA version for that matter) that works on Windows then? Can I build the newer v9.0.0b1 on Windows from source maybe?

```
C:\Windows\system32>python -m pip install -U setuptools pip
Requirement already satisfied: setuptools in c:\users\c\appdata\local\programs\python\python38-32\lib\site-packages (51.1.2)
Requirement already satisfied: pip in c:\users\c\appdata\local\programs\python\python38-32\lib\site-packages (20.3.3)

C:\Windows\system32>pip install cupy-cuda111
ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement cupy-cuda111
ERROR: No matching distribution found for cupy-cuda111
```